# Woocommerce Show Total Amount Paid in order-received page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

## I want to show total price of customer's last purchase on Woocommerce order-received page.

I'll use it to see how much I've earned from client on Facebook Pixel.

Below is a picture as I want it to be.

Example:

[image]

Comment: I answered the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74316024/how-to-get-woocommerce-last-order-amount/74316255 

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi. I pasted this code in functions.php and i put a code under Thank you. Your order has been received. this and didn't work.


<br><?php echo $order->get_total(); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></br>

Comment: The code only works on url of type

https://www.EXAMPLE.com/checkout/order-received/514/?key=wc_order_iYzlPMQCxwPk8

Comment: The URL you mentioned is called: The order Received page and I provided you with a solution for this page. Please provide a clear screenshot from your functions.php so that I can see what was wrong.

Comment: When i paste your code in functions.php this, this code appears when opening the site:
array(0) { } 
When i delete var_dump($latest_order);  and add_action('init', 'my_function'); it goes

Comment: I want the customer to see the amount of their last order when they go to the following url : example.com/checkout/order-received 

Just like that.  Thank you. Your order has been received. Total: $50

Comment: For example: https://ibb.co/x5H1RX4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use filter on thank you page `woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text`.

Try out this code in your theme functions.php.

```
function zillion_add_thankyou_custom_text_with_order_details($text)
{

    if (is_user_logged_in()) {

        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $customer = new WC_Customer($user_id);
        $last_order = $customer->get_last_order();
        if($last_order){
            $text .= '<div> Total : ' . $last_order->get_formatted_order_total() . '</div>';
        }
    }
    return $text;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', 'zillion_add_thankyou_custom_text_with_order_details');
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! I put this code 

<?php echo $customer->get_formatted_order_total(); ?>

under 

<p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--success woocommerce-thankyou-order-received"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', esc_html__( 'Thank you. Your order has been received.', 'woocommerce' ), null ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></p>

//////////////////////////////////////
 in woocommerce/checkout/thankyou.php

Comment: It worked but it gave me this error.  A critical error has occurred on your website.

https://ibb.co/MfjfTPZ

Comment: You are pasting the wrong code `<?php echo $customer->get_formatted_order_total(); ?>` it is not a customer object's function. it is only used for order object.

Comment: What should i do?

Comment: It was fixed when I deleted the code, but i didn't understand. Was it enough to just paste that code into functions.php to make it happen?

Comment: yeah, it's enough. you don't have to do anything else.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have one last question. Can we show 0.00 if there is no purchase? If you want mark i can create new question.