# How to get WooCommerce Last Order Amount?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show customers latest orders amount in order-received page.

I'll use this for my facebook pixel to see how much i earned from this customer.

I think it can be with functions.php

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it **[`get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/)** function by getting orders from a specific customer. I have coded it with comments for writing an explanation. Hope it helps.

```
function my_function(){
    $customer = wp_get_current_user(); // Your Customer User ID goes here.
// Get all customer orders
    $customer_orders = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => 1, // Put numberposts 1, so you get only the latest one, but you have to sort it by date and DESC. See below
        'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
        'orderby' => 'date', // I just sorted it by date in DESC, so you get the latest one
        'order' => 'DESC', // Descending order set
        'meta_value' => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type' => wc_get_order_types(),
        'post_status' => array_keys(wc_get_order_statuses()), 'post_status' => array('wc-processing'), // You may consider the order status
    ));

    $latest_order = []; //
    foreach ($customer_orders as $customer_order) {
        $orderq = wc_get_order($customer_order);
        $latest_order[] = [
            "ID" => $orderq->get_id(),
            "Value" => $orderq->get_total(),
            "Date" => $orderq->get_date_created()->date_i18n('Y-m-d'),
        ];

    }

    var_dump($latest_order); // I did a var_dump here to see output
}
add_action('init', 'my_function'); // I hooked it on init, you may hook it wherever you need
```

Code is tested and works. You should get output like given below:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["ID"]=>
    int(10806)
    ["Value"]=>
    string(5) "40.00"
    ["Date"]=>
    string(10) "2022-11-03"
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand php very well. When I apply the codes you wrote in functions.php Will I have received the total amount paid by the customer's last order?
And can i show it in order-received page?

Comment: Yes, You can. But you have to adjust it to use it in your way wherever you need.

Comment: Since I'm going to use Facebook Pixel, there should be no variable URL, so I want to show the total amount on EXAMPLE.com/checkout/order-received page.

Comment: You can do it, but you have to have minimum knowledge of PHP and WP to do it. I already gave a solution above which should help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. I will use this code in functions.php and i'll go to order-received page and write echo get_total(); under thank you for purchasing

Comment: If you understood, my answer above. Then you can whatever you need.